# Как вывести 4 символа из строки после первых 4-х и т.д.?

Tags: строки, bash

Есть строка состоящая из 40 символов:

```
1qa2ws3ed4rf5tg6yh7uj8ik9ol0pz2x3c4v5b6n
```

Как с помощью bash  вывести:

- первые четыре символа (cut -c1 -4)
- четыре символа после четырёх первых символов
- четыре символа после первых восьми символов

...и т.д. ?

Comment: если это читает преподаватель/экзаменатор, задавший данное задание, то можно было и проще сформулировать: убрать первые четыре символа, а остальные вывести группами по четыре.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью `cut`:

```
data="1qa2ws3ed4rf5tg6yh7uj8ik9ol0pz2x3c4v5b6n"
echo $data | cut -c 1-4
echo $data | cut -c 5-8
echo $data | cut -c 9-12
```

С помощью [раскрытия переменных](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#overview) самого Bash:

```
echo ${data:0:4}
echo ${data:4:4}
echo ${data:8:4}
```

Пример с циклом:

```
for i in {0..36..4}; do echo ${data:$i:4}; done
```

Comment: Благодарю, про  цикл вообще не знал...